# PLSQL avoid code duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I need to select from all users that are not present in a set of other sub queries:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (<userSubQuery1>)
WHERE 
    user_id NOT IN (<badUserSubQueryA>) AND
    user_id NOT IN (<badUserSubQueryB>) AND
    user_id NOT IN (<badUserSubQueryC>)
```

Only I need to do the NOT IN filters in many different queries where the userSubQuery and the badUserSubQueries may be different. E.g.:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (<userSubQuery2>)
WHERE 
    user_id NOT IN (<badUserSubQueryB>) AND
    user_id NOT IN (<badUserSubQueryC>) AND
    user_id NOT IN (<badUserSubQueryD>)
```

All the sub queries, both the ones I'm selecting from and the once used in the NOT IN are complex so I don't want to duplicate the code for the NOT IN sub queries which are often the same (badUserSubQueryB and badUserSubQueryC in my example).

I could achieve this with dynamic sql but I'd rather not if I can avoid it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

How about storing all the bad user IDs in an indexed temporary table from which you can filter?

Comment: As it's oracle, you could also use a materialized view for each of the subqueries.

Comment: How about not using performance impacting and resource draining implementations to solve what is actually a problem with the development process?

Comment: I considered having a functions that returns a plsql collection with the union of the result of all the badUserSubQueries. How would that compare performance wise to putting them in a temp table?

Comment: @user948705 In this case you could create a pipelined function returning the invalid user ids as if they were coming from a table http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html

Comment: why not create a "isUserOk(user, type)" function? (where type is "abc" or "bcd"). but then i would use dynamic sql to add the appropriate badUserSubqueries

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a view for each complex subquery that you want to reuse?

Comment: Ye if I also put the userSubQuery in a view that would help. But I'd still need to have a separate query (although simpler) for each combination.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a crack at it like this:

Try to think of this in reverse logic like this

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (<userSubQuery1>)
MINUS
(
SELECT useri_id
  FROM <badUserSubQueryB> 
UNION
SELECT useri_id
  FROM <badUserSubQueryC> 
UNION
SELECT useri_id
  FROM <badUserSubQueryD>
)
```

Let me know how it goes

Cheers ,
Alex